# jdbc url definition

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I know this question is going to get me lots of downvotes but still i am going to ask! :D
I have searched all around but my query still remains. .

jdbc connection url is- `jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/XE`

I am going to be straight with my questions:

Question 1: why do we use ":" (Colons) in the url string ? as a convention ":" are used for specifying port numbers.

Question 2: what is thin ? as far as i know thin specifies the client .. i.e thin/thick client? What is actually that ?

Question 3: what is XE ?

Comment: You are giving us the password for the database, you realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question 1: why do we use ":" (Colons) in the url string ?

Because thats the Jdbc url connect string protocol to seperate different segments like host,driver, db etc

> Question 2: what is thin ?

Thin means 100% java driver, unlike ODBC-JDBC bridge or native

> Question 3: what is XE ?

XE is schema name (db instance), in this case its default for Oracle Express Edition

Comment: 100 % java driver .. ! what is the need for 100% java driveR? why would i want to use that ?

Comment: instead of thin what are other values it can have ?

Comment: That means its 100% implemented using java, not depending on the native drivers / native software interfaces [More Here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver)

Answer (score 1):

jdbc connection url is- jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521/XE

I am going to be straight with my questions:

Question 1: why do we use ":" (Colons) in the url string ? as a convention ":" are used for specifying port numbers.
Ans.in jdbc technology,give some rule to develop jdbc persistence logic to connect with database.so,this url pattern having string type but that properties separated by semicolon to identify connection with database.
port no is unique value of database for connection purpose with database connection like oracle is 1521.

Question 2: what is thin ? as far as i know thin specifies the client .. i.e thin/thick client? What is actually that ?
Ans-thin driver having less layer implementation  internally.thin driver is best driver in java because thin do not depend dsn of database.thin driver connect with all database which is run in other server location.
thick driver having more layer implementation internally.it suitable for stand alone application. it dsn depend.

Question 3: what is XE ?
XE is service id of oracle Express edition database.it means every database having unique identify of database location to connect with database like oracle Express Edition having by default XE.

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@[host][:port]:SID`

**user** - The login user name defined in the Oracle server.

**password** - The password for the login user.

**host** - The host name where Oracle server is running. 
         Default is 127.0.0.1 - the IP address of localhost.

**port** - The port number where Oracle is listening for connection.
         Default is 1521.

**SID**  - System ID of the Oracle server database instance. 
         SID is a required value. By default, Oracle Database 10g Express 
         Edition creates one database instance called XE.

Comment: question 1 and 2 still remain!!

Comment: please, extend your answer